A generalized inequality with absolute values
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, find the maximum of $c\in\mathbb{R}$, such that for any $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfy that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i\geq c\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|$, where $b_i=\max_{1\le j\le n}\{|\sum_{k=j+1}^{i+j}a_k|\}$.
It is a generalization form from the version without absolute value sign. So far, it is known that for every odd number $n$, we have $c_{\max}=\frac{1}{2}$, using pairing method (pairing $b_k$ and $b_{k+1}$ when $k$ is even). I guess it will need condition analysis when $n$ is even, but I haven't succeeded yet. 
Maybe we can translate the inequality into a combination problem!

I take it that the $\sum a_k$ is meant to wrap around?
